# Bowls of soup: full, empty, half full. Is it possible to divide 8 of each type between 3 people and have same amount of bowls?

Tags: linear-algebra

There are 24 bowls of soup. 8 are full, 8 are empty, 8 are half full. Is it possible to split these bowls so that 3 people have the same amount of bowls and quantity of soup? Could one formulate this into a system of linear equations? Is there a way to solve without manually writing out possibilities?

Comment: in your problem, is there any condition like- the sum of number of bowls of 3 persons is equal to 24. Or any condition like- sum of quantity of soup of 3 persons equal to the total quantity  of soup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reflect on the fact that you have twelve bowls worth of soup, so each person has to get four bowls worth and eight bowls.  The ways to do that are eight halves, one full, six halves, one empty, and so on to four full and four empty.  An easy way to partition them is just to give two people four full and four empty and give the third eight halves.  Now you can have two people swap one full+one empty for two halves as much as you want.  There are many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This:
\begin{equation}
f_1+0e_1+h_1/2=4 \\
f_2+0e_2+h_2/2=4 \\
f_3+0e_3+h_3/2=4 \\
f_1+e_1+h_1=8\\
f_2+e_2+h_2=8\\
f_3+e_3+h_3=8\\
\end{equation}
$f$ full, $e$ empty, $h$ half.